# $\exists x P(x)\land\exists x Q(x)$ is not logically equivalent to $\exists x(P(x)\land Q(x) )$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

The textbook states that the solution is:

> Let P(x) be "x is positive" and Q(x) is "x is negative". The domain is
>   integers.
>
> This shows $\exists x P(x)\land\exists x Q(x)$ is True and shows $\exists x(P(x)\land Q(x) )$ is False.

I take this to mean that $\exists x P(x)\land\exists x Q(x)$ is translated into English as "There exist positive integers and there exist negative integers", which is obviously true.

I think that $\exists x(P(x)\land Q(x) )$ means "There exists an integer that is positive and negative" which is False.

Does all this mean what I think it means?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: For a follow-up exercise: what about $\forall x(Px\land Qx)$ versus $(\forall x Px)\land(\forall x Qx)$ ?

Comment: ∀x(Px∧Qx)  -> this means that "Every integer is both positive and negative" which is False.

(∀xPx)∧(∀xQx) -> this means that "Every integer is positive and every integer is negative" which is also False?

So they are logically equivalent?

Comment: @borderlineNovice They are logically equivalent, but you can't establish that by example.  Actually simplec's statement is usually an axiom.  $\forall$ is exactly just "and" written using a bound variable, and $\exists$ is exactly just "or" written using a bound variable.

Comment: @DanielV I am still trying to get a handle on quantifiers. So if we could take a look at another problem. Determine whether ∀x(P(x) --> Q(x)) and ∀xP(x) --> ∀xQ(x) are logically equivalent.

These statements are not logically equivalent. If P(x) is sometimes T and sometimes F, and Q(x) is always F, then ∀x(P(x) --> Q(x)) is False. However, ∀xP(x) --> ∀xQ(x) would be True according to the textbook. But why?

Comment: @borderlineNovice That is a correct argument using a counter example.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Ok, I think I've got it. So supposing that ∀x(Px ∧ Qx) is true, then if a is in the domain, then P(a) ^ Q(a) would be true. From this, we know that P(a) is True and Q(a) is True from the definition of conjunctions. So as P(a) and Q(a) are true for all elements of the domain, then ∀xP(x) and ∀xQ(x) are True. This shows that ∀xP(x) ∧ ∀xQ(x) is True. Thus, the statements are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right, and the comments to your question are probably more interesting than my answer. Still, I'd like to make the point of **scopes**.

The **scope** of a logical connective corresponds to the statements that it connects.

For instance, in $A\lor B$, it should be clear to you that both $A$ and $B$ are in the scope of $\lor$: that's how you evaluate it. Scopes become your first priority as soon as the proposition is a bit more complex. Take $A\lor B\land C$ for example. As you know, this is not a well-formed formula of sentential logic. However, adding parentheses helps you decide whether $(A\lor B)\land C$ or $A\lor(B\land C)$ is meant: the scopes of both connectives are then well-defined.

The same rules apply to quantifiers, both existential and universal.

As you correctly pointed out, it's easy to understand through a simple example how $\exists x Px\land\exists xQx$ and $\exists x(Px\land Qx)$ differ. In the second case, the scope of the existential quantifier is extended to the inside of the brackets: both the $x$ in $Px$ and $Qx$ refer to the same variable $x$, instantiated by the existential quantifier.

On the contrary, in the first case, the scopes of the existential quantifiers are limited by the conjunction, i.e.: $$(\exists x\underbrace{Px}_{\text{scope 1}})\land(\exists x\underbrace{Qx}_{\text{scope 2}})$$ which could as well be rewritten with a new variable to avoid confusion: $$\exists xPx\land\exists yQy$$ To go even further, this is equivalent to: $$\exists x\exists y(Px\land Qy)$$
(This is referred to as [Prenex Notation](http://www.internetlogic.org/slip25b.htm)).